# QT QUdpSocket: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, qt, udp

I am using QT Creator to build a program that receives `UDP` data packets.

I am trying to include `QUdpSocket` library, but it throws the following error (triplicated in the same line):

> mainwindow.h:6: error: C1083: 'QUdpSocket': No such file or directory

I've included `QT += network` line to `.pro` file, but it keeps returning the error.

I've checked that I have `QUdpSocket` and `qudpsocket.h` files in "C:\Qt\5.5\msvc2012\include\QtNetwork" directory.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

**Version: Qt Creator 3.4.1 based on Qt 5.4.2 (MSVC 2013, 32bit)**

Comment: Add `#include <QUdpSocket>` into your `mainwindow.h`.

Comment: this may sound trivial, but have you ran `qmake` again? and maybe `make clean` ?

Comment: I've added <QUdpSocket>, cleaned and built, but it remains equal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add following to your source code file:

```
include <QtNetwork/QUdpSocket>
```

Comment: Ok, it worked!


I noticed that two project's directories were in "My documents", so I moved them to a single empty directory. After restarting the program, it built it fine.

Thank you so much!